# How to capture those records that was unable to get inserted?

Tags: exception, error, dmlexception

Say, I have a list of **1000** records to be inserted. How to capture those records that failed to get inserted? I realize that I can use DMLException to get the error. But how to get a list of failed insertions. Here's a situation I created to demonstrate my requirement.

```
Account[] accts = new List<Account>();
for(Integer i=0;i<1000;i++) {
Account a = new Account(Name='Acme' + i, BillingCity='San Francisco');
accts.add(a);
}
Account accountToUpdate;
try
{
   insert accts;        
} 
catch(DmlException e) 
{
 System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Say record **Acme50** and **Acme62** didn't get inserted. How to get a list of failed records?

Comment: Do you have to do this through code?  i.e. is this for test coverage?  Or would you be better to use the Data loader?

Comment: Its not a requirement. Just curious about how to achieve this through apex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Database.insert()` method and get results by using `Database.SaveResult`.

Also, have a look at the DML parameter `optAllOrNone` [documented here.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm) if you want to roll back the operation in case 1 record fails.

Example code:

```
List <Contact> contacts = new List <Contact> ();

Contact contact1 = new Contact();
contact1.FirstName = 'TestFirstname';
contact1.LastName = 'TestSurname';
contacts.add(contact1);

Contact contact2 = new Contact();
contact2.FirstName = 'TestFirstname';
contacts.add(contact2);

// Assuming contact2 will fail not having last name populated
List <Database.SaveResult> saveResults = Database.insert(contacts, false);

// Go through each result
for (Database.SaveResult saveResult : saveResults)
{
    if (saveResult.isSuccess() == true)
    {
        // Successfully inserted contact
        // do something 
    }
    else
    {
        // Failed
        for(Database.Error error : saveResult.getErrors())
        {
            System.debug('Something went wrong with the record ID ' + saveResult.getId() + ' : ' + error.getStatusCode() + ' - ' + error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. A cue from a fellow stackexchange user. Thanks #rao

Answer (score 0):

I tried with same code in case of failure but saveResult.getId() is null. we need the ids of the failure records.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_Database_SaveResult_getId

Salesforce says if it not success then saveResult.getId() will be blank.

Any idea how to capture the failure records ID?