# Account visibility for Territory management

Tags: master-detail, territory-management, territory

I'm facing a problem after creating a new MD relation **account__c** for a custom object **subscribe__c** for territory management.

When I click on the lookup button for account__c field, I get a list of recent account only!

Also, If I type words on the lookup **text field** on the lookup dialog, It shows other accounts too! Here's the lookup dialog...

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know

1) you can try using URL hacking technique and pass the Search value (if only you are using a custom visual force page, if not you enter into sidebar hacking techniques which partially is supported through links) even this approach may fail with some browsers when the length of the URL exceeds 2000 (some big random number) chars.

2) We have implemented a technique in our org that has been accepted by our users.
You need to make sure you restrict the data that is getting display in the lookup window through lookup filters, you do not want the user to sit for a while (or) scroll through 100's of records ( not sure about the limit / number of records you can display on the lookup window though)

**Step 1:** Create a dummy read only field on account and call it "All"

**Step 2:** Use data loader ( if you have a lot of records in your org) or use multiselect option ( I had only 30 records to update) and update the value of the newly created All field to "All"

**Step3:** On your **lookup window text** ( this is the actual name under lookup filter settings on any custom lookup field) type something like

1) Type "All" in the search box.
2) Choose "All Fields" from the Search options and click "Go".

This should give you all the records matching your filter criteria in your lookup window,

Finally show some love for this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxgoAAA

Comment: Sounds innovative. But what values will the All read only field contain?

Comment: "All" field contains "All", it is a dummy field to make the user type "All"as the search string and search for all records.

Comment: @MnZ if your queries are answered please start marking them solved for 2 reasons 1) it increases the communities solved ratio 2) solved questions catch attention of everyone than unanswered ones. your acceptance ratio looks very low, please relook the questions and see if you can mark a few solved on which you were personally satisfied with the answer like this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/how-to-capture-those-records-that-was-unable-to-get-inserted