# How can I find problematic records in a dml action?

Tags: dml, database

Let's assume I have a list of 100 new records that I want to insert, 10 of these records are missing information which will result in DML exception.

Is there a way for me to create a list and include all the problematic records in it?

Comment: Are you running an anonymous apex script, inserting using an apex class, or using a tool such as dataloader?

Comment: I want to build a class that sends out emails to the developers if there is an issue/error.

Comment: this can help probably https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42417/how-to-capture-those-records-that-was-unable-to-get-inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SaveResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) methods.

If you insert the records using `Database.insert` / `Database.update`  with a false second parameter (allOrNothing) to allow partial processing of records on failure you will be able to retrieve an array of SaveResult objects. Each of those SaveResult records has a *isSuccess()* method which returns false in case the DML operation was not successful. From there you are able to retrieve the specific error per record that failed to be inserted and/or updated.

If you want to do the same for a `Database.delete` method instead then you need to use the [DeleteResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_deleteresult.htm) class.